# What is the easiest way I can create a 'beep' sound from a Ruby program?

Tags: ruby, beep

I'm making a small ruby command line script and I wanted to know what the simplest way to have the program emit a beep is.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Try printing the audible bell character:

```
print "\a"
```

Comment: How do I customize this beep sound? I want to play a different beep sound than the default one.

Thanks

Comment: You can't, these are ansi escape codes to control the terminal - but maybe you could play beeping and sleeping in between to produce different sequences.. checkout https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Example_of_use_in_shell_scripting

Comment: interestingly, this only results in one `beep` for me:

`3.times { print "\a\a\a"; sleep 3 }`

‍♀️

Comment: multiple beeps prevented for me by my SSH client (putty).

Answer (score 42):

For Mac OS X:

```
system('say "beep"')
```

Conventional `print "\a"` didn't always work by some reason for me (MBA, 10.7.4)

Comment: That's certainly a way to do it.

Comment: make sure you use double quotes and you are in a real terminal  - worked in macos default terminal, iterm2 also in linux terminals . In macos, if you have volume === 0 then the screen flashes since laptops seem to use sound card for beeping and not internal speaker as good old desktop PCs. It didn't work on a PTY like in the vscode terminal  - it should work on tmux, or ssh sessions I think. Not sure about windows terminals - probably works on git shell cygwin, etc

Answer (score 12):

For windows, use the win32-sound gem - [Adding Sound to Your Ruby Apps](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/05/adding-sound-to-your-ruby-apps.html).

To install:

```
gem install win32-sound
```

Then in Ruby:

```
require 'win32/sound'
include Win32
...
Sound.beep(100, 500)
```

For non-windows, looks like this could work: [How to make beep sounds?](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/178032)

```
puts 7.chr
```

Comment: You could save valuable bytes on that last one by doing `putc 7`. Do your part to address the byte shortage!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is `puts 7.chr`

Here is a customize way

```
require "Win32API"
Beep = Win32API.new("kernel32", "Beep", ["I", "I"], 'V')
def beep freq, duration
  Beep.call(freq, duration)
end 

beep 600, 400
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
$stdout.beep
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, what version of Ruby is it in and is it document anywhere?

Comment: I think you need to have an apple macintosh. I tried on a linux ssh and it failed. And surely it wouldn't work on Windows or HaikuOS.

Comment: Nope, it's not a Mac thing.

Comment: Works in Ruby 2.6 on macOS Catalina.