# Local Rails server is beeping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I run some Rails processes where the local server prints encrypted text via `puts` and `logger.debug`.

Sometimes I get 'beep' sounds, which I think are due to the server interpreting the text it's being asked to print.

How can one print encrypted text to the server without having it go 'beep' as if something's wrong?

Comment: Interesting - I've never experienced this, nor do I suspect it is the source of your beeping... Do you have example text that causes a beep via puts or logger.debug?

Comment: I wish I did! Lots of things are happening in short succession and they're different every time. I haven't been able to identify what line is causing it.

Comment: Could it be from this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621299/what-is-the-easiest-way-i-can-create-a-beep-sound-from-a-ruby-program

Comment: Well, it's possible - the server is printing a string of highly diverse, almost random characters. I'm experimenting with `force_encoding('utf-8')`.

Comment: May be some thing is printing the "\a"  `audible bell` character?